# Is it possible to create a custom Workflow Foundation Receive activity not based upon WCF?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

In our company, we have created a custom [Message Oriented Middleware](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-Oriented_Middleware) Platform to exchange messages between various entities. This Platform uses a custom messaging subsystem based upon [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/) Service Bus [Topics and Subscriptions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/).

I would like to add the capability to orchestrate the exchange using Workflow Foundation.

In my view, I will need to build a set of custom activities, in order to be able to send and receive messages to the underlying messaging subsytem.

How is it possible to build a custom Receive activity that can listen to our custom messaging subsystem ? Is it possible for this activity to activate the Workflow (using a CanCreateInstance property) ?

Comment: Have a look at the following link. Questioner is having a "semi-similar" question as of yours : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5425ed85-1a7d-434a-8f38-1f6b0ca3556c/how-to-post-to-receive-activity?forum=wfprerelease